# spring cloud contract verifier: Do we have @AutoConfigureRestAssuredMockMvc like @AutoConfigureMockMvc or similar?

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

Is it possible to avoid this `@Before` method to set up RestAssuredMockMvc in all the contract base classes.

```
  @Before
  public void setup() {

    RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(object); 
    //RestAssuredMockMvc.mockMvc(object); 
  }
```

Is there any annotation support to auto configure restassured mockmvc ?.

I can abstract out this method and let base classes to extend but would like to know if there are any other way of doing this setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. There isn't. It makes no sense (at least i don't see it yet) to automate the standalone setup  cause it can be customized in so many different ways. What could be automated however is the web app context setup. Anyways, I'm not familiar with any automation option for now.

Comment: Agreed. but before @AutoConfigureMockMvc comes into the picture, we set up mockmvc using MockMvcBuilders like we are doing now w.r.t RestAssured.mockMvc. Wouldn`t be a great option to load the context through annotations? Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I can imagine doing this for the web app context setup rather than the standalone version. That's because the controllers require dependencies to be injected via constructors for instance